# How to autoscale plotly plot in python when used rangeslider?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, graph, plotly, plotly-python

I have been trying to add autoscaling in plotly scatterplot (markers connected with lines - line chart) when I use a range slider or select a range on a chart itself. This question has been asked many times but I cannot get any working solution. I have a sample line plot -

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

trace = go.Scatter(x=list(df.index), y=list(df.Close))
fig.add_trace(trace)

fig.update_layout(
    dict(
        title="Time series with range slider and selectors",
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list(
                    [
                        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all"),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(visible=True),
            type="date",
        ),
    )
)
fig
```

[image]

Whenever I use a range slider to select a range and select range on chart itself, I want to have auto adjusting Y-axis which will adjust its range to the current visible dataset range. How can I do that?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I have added sample data and to get it if that's useful.

```py
import yfinance as yf
vix_tickers = ['AUDJPY=X']

df = yf.download(vix_tickers,
                 auto_adjust=True, #only download adjusted data
                 progress=False,
            )
df = df[["Close"]]
df
```

which looks like this-
[image]

Comment: The code has predefined labels. Please provide the sample reproducible data for the minimal reproducible code given.

Comment: I have added the data and data source. Find it if you find it useful. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the range slider should adjust accordingly to the area you select in the plot, is it?

Comment: No, the Y-axis should adjust itself if I move a range slider. For ex., from the image in the question, if I set range slider at x-axis range 2008-2010 (dates), the Y-axis range should change to `70-90` from `original 60-110` range.

Comment: Alright. Where are you trying to render the plot? e.g.: Jupyter notebook, IDE, etc?

Comment: Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Hm I used this one: `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange=True, fixedrange=False))` to autoscale yaxis, but I see that it just work with range selection on chart itself.

Below is the full code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

trace = go.Scatter(x=list(df.index), y=list(df.Close))
fig.add_trace(trace)

fig.update_layout(
    dict(
        title="Time series with range slider and selectors",
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list(
                    [
                        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all"),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(visible=True),
            type="date",
        ),
    )
)
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange=True, fixedrange=False))

fig.show()
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I still see the fixed range after I do the range selection on the chart. Did it work for you with sample code from the question if you tried? Thanks for reply!

Comment: @PratikGhodke: yep I did based on your code, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man, it was really helpful. But this is not quite I need. Basically I want to adjust Y-axis automatically whenever I move the range slider (bottom of the graph) and all the data points should be visible nicely. Your solution works only if I select an area on the chart. Thanks for the efforts. Really appreciate it!